# Express---routes and "app"?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

I have the following Express code in the initial routes file of my MVC setup. This is the entire file. What I am trying to determine is whether the `app` after the require statement is able to reference the `var app = express()` declaration in my main server.js file?

```
module.exports = function(app){
 require('./main')(app);
};
```

Comment: You're passing in `app`, it doesn't need to access anything from `server.js`

Comment: Guess I am trying to figure out what exactly `app` is then if it isn't the Express reference from `server.js`. I'll try console.logging it.

Comment: It *is*, but you're not referencing it *directly* -- you're passing it in.